# MSSQL Include Rows in table if COUNT returns a value of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a list of different stores, all given by 3 letter acronyms. Each store owns a certain number of apples. Each store has sold a certain number. By using the below query, I am displaying the store acronym, store name, how many apples have been sold, and how many total they owned at the beginning:

```
select distinct si.[Shop Code], ai.[Shop Name], count(si.[Apples Sold]), ai.[Total Apples]
from [Apple Database 1] si
left join [Apple Database 2] ai
    on si.[Shop Code] = ai.[Grocery Store Code]
where si.[Apple Status Code] = '13'
and si.[Shop Code] like ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr')
and si.[Status] = 'Complete'
group by si.[Shop Code], ai.[Shop Name], ai.[Total Apples]
```

Apple Status Code and Status are two columns that both are needed to indicate that the apple was sold and the purchase/process is 'Complete'. Here is the result data set THAT I WANT:

| Shop Code | Shop Name | Apples Sold | Total Apples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Store A | 3 | 8 |
| def | Store D | 10 | 24 |
| ghi | Store G | 1 | 3 |
| jkl | Store J | 4 | 4 |
| mno | Store M | 0 | 3 |
| pqr | Store P | 0 | 2 |

However, this is the dataset that I ACTUALLY GET:

| Shop Code | Shop Name | Apples Sold | Total Apples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Store A | 3 | 8 |
| def | Store D | 10 | 24 |
| ghi | Store G | 1 | 3 |
| jkl | Store J | 4 | 4 |

I understand that the And clauses filter out the shop's that don't meet those requirements, my thoughts where to do a sub query within the count clause, but I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: And you don't need both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` - in fact your should nearly never use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: And without seeing the sample data that should produce those results, it pretty difficult for us to assist you. Help us to help you, provide a [mre].

Comment: Separate from your missing rows, I noticed two things that do not look right with your query. (1) Should your `like` operator be an `in` condition? I do not believe `like` forks with lists. (2) Are you sure you want to select `count(si.[Apples Sold])` and not `sum(si.[Apples Sold])`?

Comment: @TN I have to use count because each apple in the background is marked with an individual registry number, so it has to count the distinct ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to solve the problem by moving the WHERE condition into your count(si.[Apples Sold]).

Something like:

```sql
select si.[Shop Code], ai.[Shop Name], SUM(case when si.[Status] = 'Complete' and si.[Apple Status Code] = '13' then si.[Apples Sold] END), ai.[Total Apples]
from [Apple Database 1] si
left join [Apple Database 2] ai
    on si.[Shop Code] = ai.[Grocery Store Code]
where si.[Shop Code] like ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr')
group by si.[Shop Code], ai.[Shop Name], ai.[Total Apples]
```

Also, i changed the COUNT to SUM because it makes more sense, as well as did some other fixes.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Only issue is that using sum gave me an error, using count worked for it.

Comment: Hmm. What values does [Apples Sold] contain? Please don't write VARCHAR

Comment: Does that `like (...)` syntax actually work? What DBMS is that?

Comment: I'm guessing mysql!